# Dismiss UIViewController sheet from SwiftUI with Binding/Presentation Mode?

Tags: swift, admob, uikit, swiftui, modalviewcontroller

I have a SwiftUI view with a sheet that directs to a UIViewControllerRepresentable struct, which uses a Google Ad Manager extension. I want the UIKit extension to dismiss the sheet when it's done running using presentation mode, but using presentation mode through the environment isn't working. Is the code not running the way I've set it up, or is it not possible to dismiss the sheet from the Google Ads Manager?

Alternatively, when I try to dismiss the sheet using a Binding to update isPresented in AdManager, I get the error message: "Property 'self.isPresented' not initialized at super.init call". When I try to initialize it, however, it says I can't do it before super.init, and when I put it after super.init, it says I can't call it after super.init. Is there any way I can dismiss the sheet when the ad is done loading (the function rewardedAdDidDismiss)?

*Edit: This post was originally marked as a duplicate, but the linked question asked about dismissing a SwiftUI modal from a UIViewController, not the other way around.*

The SwiftUI view:

```
    import SwiftUI

struct AdRevenue: View {
    @State var playAd = false
@Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode: Binding<PresentationMode>

var body: some View {
    Button(action: {
            self.playAd = true
                    })
            {
                Text("Play Ad")
            }.sheet(isPresented: $playAd) {
                Ads()}
}
}
```

This is my UIViewControllerRepresentable:

```
 import GoogleMobileAds
import SwiftUI
import UIKit

struct Ads: UIViewControllerRepresentable {

typealias UIViewControllerType = UIViewController


func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> UIViewController {
    return ViewController()
}

func updateUIViewController(_ uiView: UIViewController, context: Context) {
}


class ViewController: UIViewController, GADRewardedAdDelegate, AdManagerRewardDelegate {

var rewardedAd: GADRewardedAd?

@Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode: Binding<PresentationMode>

override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()

    AdManager.shared.loadAndShowRewardAd(AdIds.rewarded.rawValue, viewController: self)
    AdManager.shared.delegateReward = self
    presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()

    }


    func rewardedAd(_ rewardedAd: GADRewardedAd, userDidEarn reward: GADAdReward) {
      print("Reward received: \(reward.type), amount \(reward.amount).")
    }

}
}
```

This is my Google Ads Manager:

```
    public protocol AdManagerRewardDelegate{
func rewardAdGiveRewardToUser(type:String, amount: NSDecimalNumber)
func rewardAdFailedToLoad()
func rewardAdDidReceive(
    rewardViewController: UIViewController?,
    rewardedAd: GADRewardedAd?,
    delegate: AdManager
)
func rewardAdDidOpen()
func rewardAdDidClose()
func rewardAdFailedToPresent()
}


//default implementation AdManagerRewardDelegate
public extension AdManagerRewardDelegate{
func rewardAdGiveRewardToUser(type:String, amount: NSDecimalNumber) {}
func rewardAdFailedToLoad() {}
func rewardAdDidReceive(
    rewardViewController: UIViewController?,
    rewardedAd: GADRewardedAd?,
    delegate: AdManager
) {
    if rewardedAd?.isReady == true {
        if let rewardViewController = rewardViewController {
            rewardedAd?.present(fromRootViewController: rewardViewController, delegate: delegate)
        }
    }
}
func rewardAdDidOpen() {}
func rewardAdDidClose() {}
func rewardAdFailedToPresent() {}
}

public class AdManager: NSObject {
public static let shared = AdManager()
public var ADS_DISABLED = false
public var delegateReward: AdManagerRewardDelegate?

private var viewController:UIViewController?
private var rewardViewController:UIViewController?

private var testDevices:[String] = [""]

private var rewardedAd: GADRewardedAd?

@Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode: Binding<PresentationMode>

let borderSizeBetweenBannerAndContent:CGFloat = 5

public override init() {
    super.init()
}


public func configureWithApp(){
    GADMobileAds.sharedInstance().requestConfiguration.testDeviceIdentifiers = testDevices
}

public func setTestDevics(testDevices: [String]){
    self.testDevices = testDevices
    self.testDevices += [kGADSimulatorID as! String ] //all simulator
}

private func getGADRequest() -> GADRequest{
    let request = GADRequest()
    return request
}


// MARK:- Reward Video Ads
public func loadAndShowRewardAd(_ adUnit: String, viewController: UIViewController){
    self.rewardViewController = viewController

    rewardedAd = GADRewardedAd(adUnitID: adUnit)
    rewardedAd?.load(getGADRequest()) { error in
      if let error = error {
        // Handle ad failed to load case.
        print("Reward based video ad failed to load. \(error.debugDescription)")
        self.delegateReward?.rewardAdFailedToLoad()
      } else {
        // Ad successfully loaded.
        print("Reward based video ad is received.")
        self.delegateReward?.rewardAdDidReceive(
            rewardViewController: self.rewardViewController,
            rewardedAd: self.rewardedAd,
            delegate: self
        )
      }
    }
}
}

// MARK:- GADRewardBasedVideoAdDelegate
extension AdManager : GADRewardedAdDelegate {
public func rewardedAdDidPresent(_ rewardedAd: GADRewardedAd) {
    print("Rewarded ad presented.")
    delegateReward?.rewardAdDidOpen()
}

public func rewardedAd(_ rewardedAd: GADRewardedAd, didFailToPresentWithError error: Error) {
    print("Rewarded ad failed to present.")
    delegateReward?.rewardAdFailedToPresent()
}

public func rewardedAdDidDismiss(_ rewardedAd: GADRewardedAd) {
    presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
    print("Rewarded ad dismissed.")
    delegateReward?.rewardAdDidClose()
}

public func rewardedAd(_ rewardedAd: GADRewardedAd, userDidEarn reward: GADAdReward) {
    print("Reward received with currency: \(reward.type), amount \(reward.amount).")
    delegateReward?.rewardAdGiveRewardToUser(type: reward.type, amount: reward.amount)
}
}
```